# How do stalemates affect your rank?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've experimented a bit against the computer and found that upon a stalemate being detected, the "defeat" message is shown. But in a ranked game do stalemates count as defeats for both players? How do stalemates affect ladder points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In normal ladder games, the higher ranked person will lose points and the lower ranked person will gain points. The point gain/loss is less than a straight up loss or win.

In automated tournaments, the person who scored the most experience points in the game will advance. It does not take into account rank or MMR.